# Android crops invisible parts of views inside RelativeLayout

Tags: android, scroll, android-relativelayout, crop

I have a RelativeLayout that contanins other Layouts (views) positioned by margins. I also have a GestureDetector that detects scrolling and does calls scrollBy() for RelativeLayout:

```
 public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
        float distanceY) {
    int dx = (int) distanceX;
    int dy = (int) distanceY;
    sdx+= dx; sdy+= dy;
    container.scrollBy(dx, dy);
    return false;
 }
```

When I scroll it, I get a problem:

[image]

If a child view is positioned partially off-screen, I get it cropped when swiping right or bottom. But if some view is totally invisible at first time, they looks good when shown. What is the problem? Maybe I need to add some attribute to container (tried android:clipChildren, android:clipToPadding, android:isScrollContainer)? Help me please!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

By default, there is no mechanism in place that tells the child views of a parent that they need to redraw themselves on a scroll event.  The scrollable widgets in the SDK handle this in a variety of specific ways.  Your simplest option would likely be to subclass your `RelativeLayout` container so you can override `onScrollChanged()` and use this callback to call `invalidate()`.  This will tell the container (and subsequently its children) that it needs to redraw after the scroll.

You might be able to get away with calling `container.invalidate()` directly after calling `container.scrollBy()` in your gesture callback. I'm not sure if that's calling `invalidate()` too soon; though this method will also fall apart if you attempt to do any smooth scrolling.

HTH

Comment: Thank you for reply, I tried to call container.invalidate() after scrollBy() but it didn't take effect, still can't make any updates before end of gesture. Child views that placed totally outside the visible area are good but views that have a visible part before scrolling are cropped (only near the right and bottom borders)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a `RelativeLayout` at the top level (managing paging of custom PageView class). This parent class width and height is set to `MATCH_PARENT`

The PageView was also a `RelativeLayout` and managed its own size and scroll position based on motion events caught by its own `ScaleGestureDetector` and `GestureDetector` classes. It also has a large number of dynamic Views added (EditText, RadioGroup, checkbox, SurfaceView for drawing etc)

I was finding that when the child views had their size/location changed in response to a change on the PageView, any child that existed entirely inside or outside the screen display area had the correct dimensions. An others that crossed the region defined by the screen had the correct position, but the size (both width and height) were cropped to the window border. This was regardless of any of the `RelativeLayout` properties set, or at least so it appeared to me.

**The solution** in my case was to change the outer most container from a `RelativeLayout` to a `FrameLayout` and boom, fixed. Hence `FrameLayout` (for paging) containing a single resizable `RelativeLayout` (for a page) containing multiple dynamic components for form elements.